# Is it possible to export Roblox models as .fbx files?

Tags: modeling, roblox

I'm making a model in Roblox right now for use in another game (Yes, I'm bad at using other modeling software).

Is it possible to export Roblox models as .fbx files?

- Save to File only allows you to export as .rbxm or .rbxmx
- Export Selection only allows you to export as .obj

Comment: With Blender, you can convert obj files to fbx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export as .obj and then insert into Blender and then export as .fbx?